# Running a js function in an iframe, IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-7

Currently I'm using this, to save the content from an iframe (IE only)

```
var $iframe = $('#auditframe').get(0).contentWindow;

$iframe.document.open("text/xml", "replace");
$iframe.document.write(xml);
$iframe.document.execCommand('SaveAs',true, 'test.xml');
```

This works, except on some computers running IE7. The `document.execCommand` works when I use it on the main page though, but not from the iframe. Is there any way to modify this code to some other alternatives? Or what might be causing this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is your xml coming from?

Comment: @jerjer its the content of the iframe.

Comment: i mean, did you generate the xml from javascript?

Comment: @jerjer Yes, and its working in almost all cases. Besides some ie7 instances as i mentioned...

Comment: this might be due to some security restrictions of IE7, to get around with this limitation it is better to send the xml string to the server and let server side script streamed it as an xml file, this will now be cross browser and you will no longer be dependent of document.execCommand.

Comment: @jerjer the problem is that this page cannot use a webserver. It should work offline.

Comment: owwws thats a really big problem, try lowering the security setting of IE to medium or medium low.

Comment: @jerjer see my answer below. For some reason it doesnt work in SP3 though, so my problem still remains. Sigh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer + fix for sp2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929863